# HTML Jquery Button ID

Tags: jquery, html

I want that is sent with the click of the button, the ID 
unfortunately he will send me anything. Why?

```
function streamserver_ausgabe() {
    $.get(
        'http://localhost/panel/backend/frondend/ajax_content/stream_edit.php', 
        {stream_id: this.id}
    ).done( function(data) {
            $('#ausgabe').html(data);   
    })
}

<button class="btn btn-primary" id="44" onclick="streamserver_ausgabe(this.id)">Streamserver</button>
```

Comment: Look in the [JavaScript error console](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners). Are there any errors? Where's the `#ausgabe` element?

Comment: if you want the btton id then pass event parameter to your function and retrive that using event.target.id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to accept parameter here...

```
function streamserver_ausgabe(this_id) {
        // use the passed param instead of `this.id`
        $.get('http://localhost/panel/backend/frondend/ajax_content/stream_edit.php', {stream_id: this_id}).done( function(data) {
            $('#ausgabe').html(data);   
        })
    }

<button class="btn btn-primary" id="44" onclick="streamserver_ausgabe(this.id)">Streamserver</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the function you are trying to access `this.id`. Since you aren't calling the function in any context, that will be `window.id`.

You need to use the argument you are passing to the function.

```
function streamserver_ausgabe(give_the_argument_a_name) {
```

then use it:

```
{stream_id: give_the_argument_a_name}
```

Better yet, use [a modern method to find you event handlers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener).